# Flutter app thats read real time sensor value using Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, iot, nodemcu

I want to make some IoT App (without sign in). The App is reading sensor data from the Firebase realtime database. the database shown below:

[image]

I want some function to read the value of current and power then convert it into a float value on the flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that reads the value of `current` and `power` and convert them into `float` (`double` in `Dart`) values.

```dart
  Future<void> readSensorValues() async {
    final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot =
        await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('monitor').once();
    final Map<String, dynamic> data =
        Map<String, dynamic>.from(dataSnapshot.value);

    final double current = (data['current'] as int).toDouble();
    final double power = data['power'];

    print('current is $current'); // current is 1.0
    print('power is $power'); // power is 140.8
  }
```